# Linked server with same server name

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, server-name

I'm creating a linked server, to another one that have the same server name with the local the server "HP-PC".

So when entering the name of the linked server, I have this error message : 
"You cannot create a local SQL Server as Linked server". Because it is the same server name, it refers to the local one, so how can I refer to the second ?

Hope someone can help.

Comment: Can you dod it by FQDN or IP?  I'm not sure why you'd have to machines on the same domain with the same name - sounds like a network config error.

Comment: I just set "HP-PC" as name of linked server. I didn't specify the FQDN. Is there a way to do it for linked server ?

Comment: not sure I understand the question - please list the FQDN of the 2 machines.

Comment: thank you @BrianRiley for your help. please the my answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the computer name, then changing the server name :

1. sp_dropserver 'HP-PC'
2. sp_addserver 'NEW_SERVER_NAME'
3. SELECT * from sys.sysservers
4. the new server name must appear

[for more info about changing the server name](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2525/steps-to-change-the-server-name-for-a-sql-server-machine/)